# Callback for MediaRouteButton detect devices

Tags: android, casting, chromecast

I have a problem with cast SDK V3 for Android. I can't find and setup callback for MediaRouteButton, when it becomes visible (detects chromecast device).
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you explain the usecase?

Comment: Hi, I want to start casting of item, which was externally selected. In onCreate I handle intent and got uri and then want to send it to chromecast, but it takes some time to scan chromecsaat devices and when I call showDialog for MediaRouteButton I got NullPointerException. Thank You!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have a few options and you need to experiment to see which one fits your case:

1. You can use [`CastContext`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/cast/framework/CastContext) to register a [`CastStateListener`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/cast/framework/CastStateListener). This listener provides information on the state of cast, one of them being "no cast device available", for example, so you can see when a cast device becomes available.
2. You can use [`DiscoveryManagerListener`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/cast/framework/DiscoveryManagerListener) which will inform you when the availability of cast device changes.
3. When you use [`CastButtonFactory`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/cast/framework/CastButtonFactory)to add your cast button using [`setUpMediaRouteButton`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/cast/framework/CastButtonFactory.html#setUpMediaRouteButton(android.content.Context,%20android.view.Menu,%20int)), you get a `MenuItem` back. You can then monitor the visibility of that menu item yourself.

Comment: Thank you a lot! The best and fully complete answer.

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same problem

I set it first : CastButtonFactory.setUpMediaRouteButton(nContext, nCastButton);

Then the addCastStateListener on CastContext;

The problem was there were not enough time for the CastButtonFactory to recognize the chromecast in my network. So the listener in the first place shoot me with "no device"

The fix was to add addSessionManagerListener on SessionManager and only on onSessionStarted or onSessionResumed to start setting the addCastStateListener  on CastContext